# Using Metal-Man Weapon

Tags: nes, mega-man-2

**How do you use Metal-Man's Weapon in Mega Man 2?**

I've beaten the boss, but have no idea how to "equip" it. It also doesn't show up when I press start.
However when I beat Wood-Man I was able to use his weapon (Leaf Shield).

Do I have to equip it or something? Entering the password doesn't help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At 1:18 you can see him select the "Next" option in the menu to get to the next page.  MetalMan's weapon is the second weapon on that page.

Comment: o my god this video is bringing back the best memories. I'm dancing in my chair.